# Kinesis Agent reports error from python stream data

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis-agent

Am trying to create a simple stream data from a python code, being appended to a log file, and load the streaming data to a Redshift cluster using a Kinesis Agent->Kinesis Firehose.

I confirm that the python code is running fine, creates streaming data which is being appended to a log file.
My kinesis agent is started successfully and I verified, and have also done appropriate configurations to pull data from the log file and push it to firehose stream.

The python file is a simple code that logs lat/long positions randomly.  This is only to do a sample firehose streaming, and hence used sample data:

```
latitude = 19.99
longitude = 73.78
file_n = '/tmp/random_lat_lon.log'

def generate_random_data(lat, lon, num_rows, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w+', 1) as output:
#        for _ in xrange(num_rows):
         while True:
            hex1 = '%012x' % random.randrange(16**12)
            flt = float(random.randint(0,100))
            dec_lat = random.random()/100
            dec_lon = random.random()/100
            output.write('%s,%.1f,%.6f,%.6f \n' % (hex1.lower(), flt, lon+dec_lon, lat+dec_lat))
            time.sleep(5)

generate_random_data(latitude, longitude, 5, file_n)
```

Output in the random_lat_lon.log file:

```
> 83d6c9f7a0be,25.0,73.782042,19.997504
> 18b69c5c5248,25.0,73.788921,19.995153
> 6a0d182996f0,91.0,73.783399,19.998097
> 431ba9e4f38e,0.0,73.781139,19.995481
```

When I check the kinesis-Agent, I see that its not working, and i am getting the following error trace:

```
(FileTailer[kinesis:python-stream:/tmp/random_lat_lon.log*]) com.amazon.kinesis.streaming.agent.tailing.FileTailer [ERROR] FileTailer[kinesis:python-stream:/tmp/random_lat_lon.log*]: Error when processing current input file or when tracking its status.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:158)
        at com.amazon.kinesis.streaming.agent.tailing.TrackedFileRotationAnalyzer.findCurrentOpenFileAfterTruncate(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazon.kinesis.streaming.agent.tailing.SourceFileTracker.updateCurrentFile(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazon.kinesis.streaming.agent.tailing.SourceFileTracker.refresh(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazon.kinesis.streaming.agent.tailing.FileTailer.updateRecordParser(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazon.kinesis.streaming.agent.tailing.FileTailer.processRecords(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazon.kinesis.streaming.agent.tailing.FileTailer.runOnce(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazon.kinesis.streaming.agent.tailing.FileTailer.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutionThreadService$1$2.run(AbstractExecutionThreadService.java:60)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$3.run(Callables.java:95)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My kinesis-Agent.json configuration is as follows:

```
{
  "cloudwatch.emitMetrics": true,
  "kinesis.endpoint": "https://kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
  "firehose.endpoint": "",

  "flows": [
    {
      "filePattern": "/tmp/random_lat_lon.log*",
      "kinesisStream": "python-stream"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my first sample lab experience with Kinesis Firehose (using Python).  Am missing something which I couldn't figure out.

Can someone please help with suggestions.  Let me know if any details required.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same problem. Looks like a [open issue](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-agent/issues/50) from amazon-kinesis-agent. I solved the problem by having a file with .dummy extension so the agent has a file to read from at any given point of time.